# Prob. 1 in Supplementary Exercises, Chap. 2, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: A group that is also a $T_1$ topological space is a topological group ...

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Here is Prob. 1 in the Supplementary Exercises in Chapter 2 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $H$ denote a group that is also a topological space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom. Show that $H$ is a topological group if and only if the map of $H \times H$ into $H$ sending $x \times y$ into $x \cdot y^{-1}$ is continuous.

And, here is Munkres' definition of *topological group*:

> A *topological group* $G$ is a group that is also a topological space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom, such that the map of $G \times G$ into $G$ sending $x \times y$ into $x \cdot y$, and the map of $G$ into  $G$ sending $x$ into $x^{-1}$, are continuous maps.

My Attempt:

> Suppose first that $H$ is a topological group. Then the maps $f \colon H \times H \to H$ and $g \colon H \to H$, defined by $$ f(x \times y) \colon= x y \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \times y \in H \times H $$
>   and 
>   $$ g(x) \colon= x^{-1} \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \in H,$$
>   are continuous.
>
> And, of course the identity map $i_H \colon H \to H$ defined by $$ i_H (x) \colon= x \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \in H,$$ is also continuous.
>
> Now as  $i_H \colon H \to H$ and $g \colon H \to H$ are continuous, so is the map $i_H \times g \colon H \times H \to H \times H$ defined by 
>   $$ \left( i_H \times g  \right) (x \times y) \colon= i_H(x) \times g(y) = x \times y^{-1} \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \times y \in H \times H,$$
>   by virtue of Prob. 10, Sec. 18, in Munkres.
>
> Finally, as the maps $i_H \times g \colon H \times H \to H \times H$ and $f \colon H \times H \to H$ are continuous, so is the composite map $f \circ \left( i_H \times g \right) \colon H \times H \to H$, by Theorem 18.2 (c) in Munkres. But, for each $x \times y \in H \times H$, we see that 
>   $$ \left( \ f \circ \left( i_H \times g \right) \ \right) (x \times y) = f \left( \ \left( i_H \times g \right) \ \right) (x \times y) = f \left( x \times y^{-1} \right) = xy^{-1}. $$
>   If we put $h \colon= f \circ \left( i_H \times g \right) $, then the map  $h \colon H \times H \to H$, defined by 
>   $$h(x \times y) \colon= xy^{-1} \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \times y \in H \times H,$$ is continuous, as required.
>
> Conversely, suppose that $H$ is a group that is also a topological space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom, such that the map $h \colon H \times H \to H$, defined by 
>   $$ h(x \times y) \colon= xy^{-1} \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x\times y \in H \times H, $$
>   is continuous. Then, for each $a \in H$, the map $g_a \colon H \to H$, defined by $$ g_a(x) \colon= h(a \times x) = a \times x^{-1} \ \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \in H, $$ is also continuous, by virtue of Prob. 11, Sec. 18, in Munkres. Let $e$ denote the identity element in $H$. Thus, in particular, the map $g (\colon= g_e) \colon H \to H$ defined by $$ g(x) \colon= e \times x^{-1} = x^{-1} \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \in H, \tag{1} $$ is continuous.
>
> Now as the identity map $i_H \colon H \to H$ is continuous and as the map $g \colon H\to H$ of the preceding paragraph is continuous, so is the map $i_H \times g \colon H \times H \to H \times H$, defined by 
>   $$ \left( i_H \times g \right) (x \times y) \colon= i_H(x) \times g(y) = x \times y^{-1} \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x \times y \in H \times H.$$
>
> Now as the maps $i_H \times g \colon H \times H \to H \times H$ and $h \colon H \times H \to H$ are continuous, so is the composite map $h \circ \left( i_H \times g \right) \colon H \times H \to H$,  by Theorem 18.2 (c) in Munkres. But, for each $x \times y \in H \times H$, we see that 
>   $$ \left( \ h \circ \left( i_H \times g \right) \ \right) (x \times y) = h \left( \ \left( i_H \times g \right) (x \times y) \ \right) = h \left( x \times y^{-1} \right) = x\left(y^{-1}\right)^{-1} = xy. $$
>   Thus map $f \colon H \times H \to H$, defined by 
>   $$ f(x \times y) \colon= xy \qquad \mbox{ for all } \ x\times y \in H \times H, \tag{2} $$  is continuous.
>
> Thus $H$ is a group that is also a topological space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom, for which we have just shown that the maps $g \colon H \to H$  and  $f \colon H \times H \to H$  given, respectively, by (1)  and (2)  above are continuous. Hence $H$ is a topological group.

Is this proof sound enough? If so, then is the presentation explicit enough? If not, then at what point is it in need of improvement?

Comment: It looks but but is very wordy.

Comment: Your notation $x\times y$ for a generic element of $X\times Y$ seems odd. Is it a usual notation ? (I'm used to $(x,y)$, and at first I thought you had made a mistake because I confused the $\times$ on elements for the group multiplication)

Comment: @Max that is the notation that Munkres also uses for an ordered pair, and it is in order to distinguish an ordered pair from an open interval.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I'm sorry for it, but I've aimed at making my proof as elementary as possible.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud.  Whoops, I ommited a word.   
It looks good but is very wordy.